# Beginner trails near Manchester UK

Tags: mountain-bike

I'm very much a novice when it comes to mountain biking. By novice I mean I have absolutely no experience of this. I have two questions

1. Are there any trails within commute from Manchester that are suitable for novices?
2. Is my bike suitable for trail work? 
   [image]

I find the bike is very hard to control on the trails. I'm constantly fighting with the bike to keep it on the trail. I could hear the back wheel constantly being tortured. This bike was serviced by me under supervision of a qualified bike mechanic @ a bike repair class. However I found the brakes aren't really that effective on the trail.

Comment: Which country? As far as I know there are cities with the same name in at least two countries.

Comment: I live in Manchester which is north west UK

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on whether or not your bike is suitable for use on trails.

As for trail in Manchester, Clayton Vale has some blue and red routes. They're not the best trails in the world (or the UK for that matter) but they're the best you'll get anywhere near the city.

They're right by the velodrome and the Manchester City FC stadium. Here:

[image: Clayton Vale map]

Comment: yeah that happens to be where I've been.